# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and making simply to do list website. when i want to save my data to local host it through errors

My JavaScript code to save data to local Storage

```
<script>
        add = document.getElementById("add");
        add.addEventListener("click", () => 
        {
            console.log("Updating...");
            let tit = document.getElementById("title").value;
            let desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
            if (localStorage.getItem('itemsJson') == null) {
                itemJsonArray = [];
                itemJsonArray.push([tit, desc]);
                localStorage.setItem('itemsJson', JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray));

            }
            if (localStorage.getItem('itemsJson') != null) 
            {
                console.log("Added Successfully!");
            }

            });
  </script>
```

and the error coming every time

````
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    <anonymous>      http://127.0.0.1:5500/ToDoList/ToDoList.html:112
    EventListener.handleEvent*   http://127.0.0.1:5500/ToDoList/ToDoList.html:110ToDoList.html:112:32

    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/ToDoList/ToDoList.html:112
    (Async: EventListener.handleEvent)

    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:5500/ToDoList/ToDoList.html:110```
````

Answer (score 0):

You did not add enough attributes to the elements you were manipulating.Please check this link [my solution](https://codepen.io/maronkoders/pen/mdRjNKa?editors=1111).I have solved your problem. Or You can just use this snippet. `<input type="text" id="title"><textarea type="text" id="description"></textarea><button id="add">ADD</button>`

Comment: Anytime buddie, but you can help others too by voting for the solution